# Saving and Loading RL model - DQN algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am training a RL model using the DQN algorithm. At every iteration, I save the model as follows:

```
agent = dqn.DQNTrainer(env=CustomEnv,config=config)
for n in range(100):
    result = agent.train()    
    agent.save()
```

I want to evluate the trained RL model using on a different environment. I am not sure how to load the checkpoint and evaluate in a different environment.

I try to load the trained model (the last checkpoint) but it throws me an error. I do the following:

```
agent.restore('./RL_saved/checkpoint-100.tune_metadata')
```

It throws me an error saying

```
unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

and when I do

```
agent.restore('./RL_saved/checkpoint-100.tune_metadata')
```

It throws me an error saying

```
Invalid magic number; corrupt file?
```

Am I loading the model in the right way? And how do I pass the environment to the loaded model?

Comment: What is DQNTrainer? Is this part of some library? how does it save? Are there any files in the directory where it is supposed to save the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this in case it helps anyone.

We first create an object of the class DQN and then load the checkpoint without using the extension `.tune_metadata`

```
agent = dqn.DQNTrainer(env=CustomEnv,config=config)
agent.restore(''./RL_saved/checkpoint-100')
```